# developing jersey restfull web service using Maven + Eclipse + Tomcat. 404 issue

Tags: eclipse, maven, restful-url

I am not able to access my sample restful service. Please let me know where could be problem is.

Here are the code snippets:

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>RestFulService</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>RestFulService</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Web.Xml**

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestfulContainer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sample</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestfulContainer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I try to access my sample service with below URL, I am ending up with 404 error.

RestFulService --> is the generated war file and I am able to see that app in tomcate manager page.

http://<>:8080/RestFulService/resources/sayHello

Thanks,
Girish K

Comment: what is the path value specified in your Java service?

Comment: What resource is at the sayHello path? is it a Java class.

Comment: Please see the below code snippet

@Path("/helloservice")
public class HelloService {

 @GET
 @Path("/hello")
 public String sayHello()
 {
  String result = "Hello from JAX-RS";
  return result;
 }
}

Answer (score 2):

provided scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

try to use these dependencies

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
```